# Matlab - Serial timeout but good data received with multibytes datatypes sending

Tags: matlab, serial-port, timeout, stm32

I am currently reading from an STM32 through UART using Matlab.

With the following program, I have been able to read single byte data (uint8, int8, char), even if several bytes come right after each others.

The problem comes when I try with multibytes datatypes (float32, uint32, ...). The console print me the received data, which is the one sent by the STM32, but the soft freezes and after the 10seconds default value timeout, I get this warning:

```
Warning: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period. 'serial' unable to read all requested data. For more information on possible reasons, see Serial Read Warnings.
```

The fact that I receive exactly the sent numbers (and that there is the good amount of bits sent when I check with an oscilloscope) tends to tell me that the problem is not from my soft in the STM32, but in the matlab interpretation, which seems to wait for something else.

Thank you all in advance for your ideas

```
clear;
clc;

% ------------------------ TWEAKING PARAMETERS -------------------------- %
port = 'COM4'; %Serial port
    % seriallist : This command list all the COM port available
baudrate = 115200; % Frequency
dataType = 'uint32'; %Data to be received and transmitted
readDelay = 0.001; %The time between 2 buffer emptying in seconds
maxDataStored = 1000; %The number of data to be stored in final file
serialInBufferSize = 1024; %The input buffer size
    %Make sure that sending frequency < serialInBufferSize / readDelay
storeCSV = 0; %Enable storage in CSV file
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------- %

totalData = 0;
maxDataReached = 0;
timeStamps(maxDataStored) = datetime;
timeElapsed = zeros(1, maxDataStored);
receivedData = zeros(1, maxDataStored, dataType);

%Creates main control panel to end serial streaming
controlPanel = figure('WindowStyle', 'docked', ...
                        'MenuBar', 'none');
stop = uicontrol('Style', 'PushButton', ...
                    'String', 'End communication', ...
                    'Position', [0, 0, 200, 40], ...
                    'Callback', 'delete(gcbf)');
drawnow;

% Initializes serial port
disp(['Initialising serial port ' port]);
s = instrfind('port',port);
if not(isempty(s)) % Destroy existing serial port
    disp(['Killing existant communication on ' port]);
    fclose(s);
    delete(s);
    clear s
end
s = serial(port,'BaudRate',baudrate, ...
    'InputBufferSize', serialInBufferSize, ...
    'Parity', 'even');
fopen(s);

startTime = datetime('now');
disp(['Port ' port ' initialised successfully at ' num2str(baudrate) ...
    ' bauds']);
disp('Beginning of communication');
disp(' ');

% Main script to stream data
while (ishandle(stop) && maxDataReached == 0)
    %The < 4 condition was an unsuccessfull test, it used to be == 0
    while (s.BytesAvailable < 4 && ishandle(stop))
        pause (readDelay);
    end
    if(ishandle(stop))
        in = fread(s, s.BytesAvailable, dataType);
        for i = 1 : length(in)
            if (totalData + 1 > maxDataStored)
               maxDataReached = 1;
               disp(' ');
               disp('Maximum amount of received data reached');
               break 
            end
            dt = seconds((datetime('now') - startTime));
            %Storage
            timeStamps(totalData + 1) = datetime('now');
            timeElapsed(totalData + 1) = dt;
            receivedData(totalData + 1) = in(i);
            %Console printing
            disp([datestr(now,'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), '  ||  ', ...
                num2str(dt, '%.3f'), ...
                's since startup  ||  received : ', ...
                num2str(in(i))]);
            totalData = totalData + 1;
        end
        pause(0.01);
    end
end

% Closes serial port
disp(' ');
disp(['Ending communication on port ' port ' ...']);
fclose(s);
delete(s);
clear s
disp('Communication ended properly (I hope so...)');

%Script termination
close(gcf);
disp(' ');
disp('Script ended');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read 4 times data bytes than available.

`in = fread(s, s.BytesAvailable, 'uint32');`, reads `s.BytesAvailable*4` bytes, because size of `uint32` elements is 4 bytes.

According to [fread (serial) documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fread.html):

> A = fread(obj,size,'precision') reads binary data with precision specified by precision.
>   precision controls the number of bits read for each value and the interpretation of those bits as integer, floating-point, or character values.

Documentation is not so clear, but the `size` argument specifies the number of elements (e.g. number of `uint32` elements), and not the number of bytes.

You can divide the size by 4:

```
dataType = 'uint32'; %Set dataType to 'uint32' or 'float32`.
in = fread(s, s.BytesAvailable/4, dataType);
```

A cleaner solution is reading `uint8` elements, and using [typecast](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html):

```
in = fread(s, s.BytesAvailable/4, '*uint8'); %The '*uint8' keeps data in uint8 class (not double).
in = typecast(in, dataType); %Convert to 'uint32' or 'single', according to dataType.
in = double(in); %Convert to double (for compatibility).
```

Comment: This is the right answer. And good advice about reading elementary `uint8` and using `typecast` to convert because that will let you adjust the endianness in case your pc is `little-endian` (they all are) but your micro is `big-endian` (many micros are). Also may be a note explaining that this will work for the `uint32` but if he wants to interpret `float32` he'll have to use a different `dataType` (even if it is the same number of byte as an `uint32`).

Comment: @Hoki there is an option selecting `s.ByteOrder = 'bigEndian'` (I never used it), and the typecast solution is not going to work... About the datatype: `float32` should be replaced with `single` when using `typecast`.

Comment: It worked with this solution. Thanks a lot for the others advices with typecast and the bytes order. Problem solved !