# Taking decimal data in MATLAB through COM port

Tags: matlab

I run a program on a stm32 controller with the help of STM32CubeIDE and output is in the form of decimal value like battery voltage is 3693 millivolt and temperature is in 10th of kelvin (means if output for temperature getting 3000 then value of temperature is 300k or 27 degree Celsius). I successfully taken string in matlab but don't know how to take value of these voltage and temperature in matlab through COM port.Please give me any suggestion.

I have written a code:

```
s=serial('COM5','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(s);
fprintf(s,'*IDN?')
out=fgets(s);
fclose(s)
```

Comment: You can use [fread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fread.html) or `fread` with [typecast](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) for reading binary data. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279436/matlab-serial-timeout-but-good-data-received-with-multibytes-datatypes-sending/58285727#58285727).

Comment: Your first task is to find out what is the actual format or **datatype** these values are coming in. You seem to say it is _binary_ (as opposed to ASCII), but you still need to know if these values are coming as `(u)int8`, `(u)int16`, `(u)int32`, `float32/single`, `double` or other format. Basically you need to know how many bytes will be sent for each value, how will they be ordered, and how should they be interpreted.

Comment: @ Rotem and @Hoki, thanks for your response sir.I am getting (u)int32 value.

Comment: I written code for taking data in matlab through port.I am very new to this environment ,so please correct me.   s=seral('COM port');fopen(s); fprintf(s,'*IDN') out=fscanf(s); fclose(s) and i am getting error "The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period. 'serial' unable to read all requested data."

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58426015/edit) and place your code there (with code formatting) rather than giving code example in comments.

Comment: @Hoki,sorry sir.I edit my question.

Comment: Read the first comment again, for binary values you have to use [`fread`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fread.html) instead of `fgets`.

Comment: @Hoki,thanks for your response sir but i am not reading binary value ,it is decimal value.And issue is that docklight shows garbage value even i configured baudrate same.

Comment: "_decimal_" is not a qualifier between "_ASCII_" and "_Binary_". Your data is coming in either one of these format, nothing else. If your data coming in are **uint32** as you mentioned earlier, then this is a _binary_ format and you need to use `fread`. Once you have the value in MATLAB, you can then apply a conversion factor (likely `c=1/1000`) to obtain the "_decimal_" value you're looking for.

Comment: Your data _represents_ decimal values but are actually integer numbers. Your processor is using [`Fixed-point arithmetic`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) to not have to deal with `floating-point` arithmetic. Read the article in the link to understand what you are getting.

Comment: @Hoki,thank you so much for your kind reply sir.